# Installing printer with vbs script

Tags: windows, printing, vbscript

Can someone help me for Christ sake, I am trying to get this script work. I am getting always a message error, see error picture". I've test the cscript string in CMD prompt (driver installation) and it works without a problem. I am using VBsEdit. Checked every lines for hours but maybe I am blind :-), I will be eternally grateful! Thanks

[image: pic]

```
CLS
@ECHO off

SET varIP=10.5.10.15
SET varDriver=4505ci KX
SET varDriverFolder=\\Prox-data2\Reception\IT\Hardware\Printer\Drivers\Triumph Adler\Win8.1-64bit\TA4505ci\KxDriver_cCD_cLP_20150212\
SET varDriverFile=\\Prox-data2\Reception\IT\Hardware\Printer\Drivers\Triumph Adler\Win8.1-64bit\TA4505ci\KxDriver_cCD_cLP_20150212\OEMSETUP.inf
SET varName=TA238
SET varLocation=TA238

Rem "Deleting TCP/IP port"
Rem CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\system32\prnport.vbs -d -r IP_10.5.10.15

Rem "Creating TCP/IP port"
CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\system32\prnport.vbs -a -r IP_10.5.10.15 -o raw -n 9100 -h 10.5.10.15

CLS
Rem "Installation message"
@ECHO.
@ECHO The BE9A-X9302-PR238 printer is currently being installed.
@ECHO.
@ECHO Please do not close this window.
@ECHO.
@ECHO Once the installation is complete this Setup window will exit.
@ECHO.

Rem "Driver installation"
CSCRIPT c:\windows\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs -a -m "4505ci KX" -h "\\Prox-data2\Reception\IT\Hardware\Printer\Drivers\Triumph Adler\Win8.1-64bit\TA4505ci\KxDriver_cCD_cLP_20150212" -i "\\Prox-data2\Reception\IT\Hardware\Printer\Drivers\Triumph Adler\Win8.1-64bit\TA4505ci\KxDriver_cCD_cLP_20150212\OEMSETUP.inf"  
CLS

Rem "Printer installation"
@ECHO.
@ECHO Completing installation.
CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -a -p "TA238" -m "4505ci KX" -r "IP_10.5.10.15"
CLS

Rem "Location configuration"
@ECHO.
@ECHO Completing installation.
CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\system32\prncnfg.vbs -t -p "TA238" -l "TA238"
CLS

Rem "Making it Default printer"
Rem CSCRIPT %windir%\system32\prnmngr.vbs -p "" -t
```

Comment: Error is in `tester.vbs` not in batch script provided...

Comment: So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know not knowing the `tester.vbs`. Even in your batch script I can't see any attempt to launch `tester.vbs`... Read and follow How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Josef, I appreciate your help but this code I copied it from this website: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1056-install-network-printer     and I made some changes. Many websites are proposing this solution to install your network printer.

Comment: Again: _premise#1_: Error is in `tester.vbs` not in batch script provided; _premise#2_: Even in your batch script I can't see any attempt to launch `tester.vbs`. A consequence should be clear: 1. find where is the `tester.vbs` launched from and 2. check `tester.vbs` content. Maybe something in _VBsEdit_? I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is probably too late, but it seems important to me to bring more clarity and completeness)

I guess you just have used wrong file extension for this code.
Should you rename it from .vbs into .bat , it would run successfully.

Now the VBScript interpreter chokes on the second line: `@ECHO off`
It doesn't like the first symbol here: `@`.
These numbers are expressed in the text of error box you've attached.

If you remove this symbol, the interpreter would die inside line #4.  And so on.